# should I install asp.net mvc 2 on a deploy machine?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm deploying an asp.net mvc 2 app on windows 2008 R2 and I get error that there is no system.web.mvc.dll, Should I install mvc2 on the deploy machine ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can actually deploy without MVC being installed on the server by deploying the MVC DLLs with your project. Put the following DLLs into your bin directory and it will run fine

```
System.Web.Mvc
System.Web.Routing
System.Web.Abstractions
```

If your server is on .Net 3.5 SP1 then you only need to deploy the Web.Mvc DLL, if its not running SP1 then you will need to deploy all 3.

There is an article by Phil Haack here detailing this more http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx

Comment: But there's no reason to not just install MVC2 though?

Comment: Its not always easy to get new software installed on a production server. This way can get past a lot of the hoops you would need to jump through to get it installed.